# Images not appearing in production - Laravel Snappy

Tags: laravel, snappy

I'm using laravel sanppy to export pdf files
when use img element to show image with src it is appear on the pdf local but is broken on production
the code of the image

```
<img src="{{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk('template-files')->url($template->signature) }}" alt="signature">
```

and i printed the url and is the correct url

Comment: share more code so we can help you